# Java BankAccount app - joptionpane/output/display objects in arraylist from database

Tags: java, database, arraylist

Need some help with case 5 & 7. 5 to display all objects and 7 to search the database/list/arraylist to display a single customer. Not sure how to nest the methods needed to pull all fields or certain fields. Any help/advice is really appreciated. Thanks in advance,

```
    package bankaccount;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class BankAccountTest 
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Database db = new Database();
    Database deleted = new Database();
    boolean done = false;
    while (!done)

    {
        int activity = IO.getInt("Please choose one of the following:"+
         "\n 1 to create new account"+ "\n 2 to delete an account"+
        "\n 3 to withdraw from an account"+"\n 4 to deposit to an account"+
         "\n 5 to list all customers"+"\n 6 to list all deleted customers"+
         "\n 7 to display single account "+"\n 8 to exit this program");

    switch(activity)
    {

  case 1:

  //Create new account
  String LastName = IO.getString("Please type last name: ");
  String FirstName = IO.getString("Please type first name: ");
  Name n = new Name (LastName,FirstName);

  //Create address object
  String street = IO.getString("Please type your address: ");
  String city = IO.getString("Please type your city: ");
  String state = IO.getString("Please type your state: ");
  String zipcode = IO.getString("Please type your zipcode: ");
  Address addr = new Address (street,city,state,zipcode);
/*        //Create Account number
  Random randomGenerator = new Random();
  int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(2000000000);
  AccountNum accno = new AccountNum(randomInt);
*/     //Create customer object
  String accno = IO.getString("Please enter the account number: ");
  Customer c = new Customer(n,addr,accno);
        //Create bankaccount object 
 double amt = IO.getDouble("Please type the opening account balance: ");
  BankAccount b = new BankAccount(c, amt);
  db.add(b);
  break;


  case 2:

  // Delete an account / copy account info to deleted database
   String key = IO.getString("Enter account number to delete: ");
       db.search(key); 
     if (db.inlist())
  {
        deleted.add(db.remove(db.getindex()));
  } else 
  {
   //Display not found
    IO.notFound();
  }
  break;


  case 3:

  // withdraw from an account
    key = IO.getString("Enter account number to withdraw from: ");
    db.search(key);
   if (db.inlist())
  {
     double amount = IO.getDouble("Enter an amount to withdraw : ");
     b.withdraw(amount);
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Current balance is: "+b.balance);

  } else 
     {
         IO.notFound();
     }
  break;  


 Case 5:

  //Display single account
  if(db.list.isEmpty())
  { 
    String s = "The list is empty";
    JTextArea text = new JTextArea(s, 6, 20);
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(text); 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, pane,
                "Current Customers", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < db.list.size(); i++)
  {
   // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " "+db.list.size());  
    String s = "These exists in the list: ";
    JTextArea text = new JTextArea(s, 6, 20);
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(text); 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, pane,
                "Current Customers List", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
  }
  break;

 case 7:
  // Display single account 
   key = IO.getString("Enter account number show: ");
   db.search(key);
   if (db.inlist())
  {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account information: "
                                    +db.getaccount().getbalance());
  } else 
     {
         IO.notFound();
     }
  break;  

  case 8:

  // exit program
      done=true;
      break;

 default:
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid choice, please choose again ", 
                                "ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
   }           
  }
  }
```

classes

```
package bankaccount;

public class BankAccount 
{
Customer cust;
double balance;

BankAccount (Customer c,double b)     
   {
        cust = c;
     balance = b;
   }

 void deposit (double amt)
   {
     balance = balance + amt;
   }

 void withdraw (double amt)
   {
     balance = balance - amt;
   }

 double getbalance ()
   {
    return balance;
   }

 Customer getcustomer ()
   {
    return cust;
   }
    }
```

&

```
package bankaccount;

public class Customer 
{
 Name name;
 Address addr;
 String accno;

 Customer (Name n, Address addy, String acc)
 {
     name = n;
     addr = addy;
     accno = acc;
 }

 Name getname()
 {
     return name;
 }

 Address getAddress()
 {
     return addr;
 }

 String getAccountNumber()
 {
     return accno;
 }

 void changeAccountNumber(String acc)
 {
     accno = acc;
 }
 }
```

&

```
package bankaccount;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Database 
{
    int index;
    boolean found;
    ArrayList<BankAccount> list;
    BankAccount acc;

Database()
{
 list = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
}

void add(BankAccount b)
{
   list.add(b);
}

BankAccount remove (int i)
{
    return list.remove(i);
}

 BankAccount getaccount()
{
    return acc;
}

ArrayList getlist()
{
    return list;
}

int getindex()
{
    return index;
}

boolean inlist()
{
    return found;
}

void search (String key)
{
    found = false;
    int i = 0;
    //int.length = list.size();

    while (i < list.size() && !found)
    { BankAccount b = list.get(i);
       if (key.equals(b.getcustomer().accno))
  {
  acc = b; found = true; index = i;
  }
else
  {
  i++;
  }
    }
}
}
```

&

```
package bankaccount;

public class Address 
{
 String street;
 String city;
 String state;
 String zipcode;     

  Address (String str, String cty, String st, String zip)
 {
     street = str;
     city = cty;
     state = st;
     zipcode = zip;
 }

 static String getstreet(String street)
 {
     return street;
 }

 public String getcity()
 {
     return city;
 } 

 public String getstate()
 {
     return state;
 }

 public String getzip()
 {
     return zipcode;
 }
}
```

Comment: lol .. gotcha. Ya I just checked.. couldn't find any way to delete a question, lol.  Thanks =)

Comment: EDIT -  code above has been edited. I need some advice on how to next the methods to show the data I need. Also, need some advice on how to show all fields from the arraylist for all customers .. not sure how to pull this information form the list/db/arraylist.

Comment: Can you get anything to print out correctly?  I find it easier to print the items first, and then add them to my text fields and panels.

Answer (score 0):

Case 5 - List All Customers

In order to get the list of customers, you have to iterate through the list containing your customers information, and print out their names.  The following for loop should do this for you.

```
for(int i = 0; i< Database.list.size();i++)
{
  System.out.println(Database.list.get(i).getName();
}
```

Please note, that this should print out the list of names, it will not place them in your JOptionPane.

Case 7 -

There are a few syntax errors that you currently have.  Lets start at the beginning, tracing through the program.

```
db.search(key);
```

Ok, this is going through the database and searching for the specified key.

```
void search (String key)
{
    found = false;
    int i = 0;
    //int.length = list.size();

    while (i < list.size() && !found)
    { BankAccount b = list.get(i);
        if (key.equals(b.getcustomer().accno))
  {
   acc = b; found = true; index = i;
  }
 else
  {
  i++;
  }
    }
}
```

This code is doing nothing, it sets b to acc, found is now true and index is equal to the location of the customers account in your database.  You should instead pass the key into the inlist() method in your database class, and use that to return true or false (by using the body of your search method).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Ive finished it but as I look over the code more and more I understand the nesting of methods a big better but being new its difficult to think through. A good point is really thinking about what you want the code to do - my professor does not stress that enough.